# What is the round circle next to the "do not dispose in household waste" icon on my Moto Droid?

Tags: motorola-droid, hardware

There is a round indicator of some sort under the battery cover approx 3/16" of an inch in diameter.  It is located to the left of the "Do not dispose with household waste" icon (looks like a trash can with an X over it.  The indicator appears white with red "X"s; I believe it has been this way since the phone was new, but I can't be sure.
What does this indicate?
[image]

Edit:  Added picture

Comment: I'm not sure asking about a sticker counts as an Android question, but others may disagree.

Comment: Could be a warning to recycle the battery instead of throwing it away.

Comment: I'd agree with @Matthew regarding this - it's a battery question, not an Android one.

Comment: To be clear, this is not part of the battery, it's on the phone body, but you have to remove the battery door to see it.  It looks like more than a simple sticker... there is a hole in the body of the phone specifically to reveal a view of it.   I'll post a photo shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it's a water damage sticker -- it might go more red if water gets on it, or something.

Comment: +1 Looks like a water damage indicator, it's that same shade of light-ish red as the cross-hatching on the water damage indicator on my company phone.

Comment: Yes, it's a water/moisture damage indicator.

Comment: Searching on "droid water damage indicator" shows lots of sources that agree.    Apparently it turns solid red if it gets wet.   Accepting answer.    Thanks.